# Applying domain name to a directory

Tags: apache2, vps, magento, virtualhost, ubuntu

I have a Linode instance of Ubuntu 10.4 using the LAMP stack to host an instance of Magento and a couple other things.  I currently have Magento set up at: `http://123.459.780.123/magento`.

When I apply my domain using the Linode tools, I can apply it so that I can access the Magento site at: `http://example.com/magento`.

I would like to host multiple sites, so that I can have `/magento`, `/mysite`, and `/aclientsite` all hosted under Apache, but have domains resolve to those paths, so that the root of the individual sites are those, so I can have `http://exampleA.com`, `http://exampleB.com` and `http://exampleC.com`.

I've done this before using tools in GoDaddy, but never using just Ubuntu and SSH access. Can someone explain what I need to do to point domains to folders in Apache?

Answer (score 10):

I'm not familiar with Linode, but all you need to do is point all the domains to server's IP address and leave the remaining for Apache [Name-based Virtual Host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html) handle, something like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin ...
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento
    ServerName magentosite.com
    ServerAlias www.magentosite.com
    ErrorLog logs/magentosite.error_log

    <Directory "/var/www/html/magento">
        AllowOverride all
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin ...
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/aclientsite
    ServerName aclientsite.com
    ServerAlias www.aclientsite.com
    ErrorLog logs/aclientsite.error_log

    <Directory "/var/www/html/aclientsite">
        AllowOverride all
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```